# Busqueda de productos minimos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Resulta que tengo dos tablas, una donde esta la informacion de los productos(items), incluyendo una columna que indica el min numero de items, y otra tabla (entrance) donde se registran las entradas y salidas de ellos.

Lo que quiero saber es como hacer una busqueda donde me muestre el id (Ul) del producto, el minimo, y la cantidad actual UNICAMENTE de los items donde la cantidad sea menor que el min del producto.

He intentado la sig. busqueda:

```
select i.ul, i.min, sum(e.Qty) 
from item as i
inner join entrance as e
on i.Ul = e.Ul  
HAVING SUM(e.Qty) < i.Min
```

pero me da 0 resultados. Lo intente con WHERE pero me muestra un error #1111-Invalid use of group function.

Espero haber sido claro y que alguien me pueda ayudar.

la estructura de las tablas es:
(intente ponerla aqui como tabla pero no pude, asi que tuve que pegarla como imagen.. sorry).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: having sin un group by, no esta bien... yo ni se que son esos campos, como para ayudarte.. tene idea que ul no es nada... (y aunque dijera item, campo u otro nombre, tampoco es nada si no lo explicas)

Comment: Generalmente, para preguntas de bases de datos, es mejor adjuntar de una vez la estructura de las tablas sobre las cuales se deben hacer la selección. En este caso, necesitamos conocer la estructura de "item" y "entrance".

Comment: El error  que te da, es porque pusiste having sin un group by

Comment: Ya puse las tablas alli, ojala me puedan entender un poco mejor. Tambien hice el intento complementando la busqueda con GROUP BY i.ul, pero me muestra un error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso de having implica utilizar group by. Según lo que indicas, es posible que la solución sea tan simple como incluir las columnas que mencionas, en ella.

```
select i.ul, i.min, sum(e.Qty) as cantidad
from item as i
    inner join entrance as e
        on i.Ul = e.Ul  
    GROUP BY i.ul, i.min
HAVING SUM(e.Qty) < i.Min
```

Si no obtienes el resultado deseado, entonces tendrás que completar un poco más la pregunta.

Comment: Ya puse las tablas alli, ojala me puedas entender un poco mejor. Tambien hice el intento complementando la busqueda con GROUP BY i.ul, pero me muestra un error de sintaxis.

Comment: La consulta que te he puesto es la buena para eso. ¿Cual es el error de sintaxis, explicito? Con Group By i.ul, i.min

Comment: Pues amigo, el error fue mio en el momento de transcribir el query. Gracias por tu ayuda, podrias recomendarme algun sitio donde pueda practicar ese tipo de busquedas que son un poco mas complejas?

Comment: Para practicar, no hay sitio mejor, que un foro como este. Busca las preguntas de otros usuarios e intenta darles respuesta. Verás todo lo que aprendes. Otro camino es intentar buscar para hacer la certificación de [desarrollador de Oracle para Mysql](https://education.oracle.com/oracle-certification-path/pFamily_406).  Tirando de ese hilo puedes conseguir cosas interesantes.